# How to reference the barItem in the Navigation Bar and change the icon

Tags: xamarin.forms

say ,Page1 and Page2 have the same number of icons as below

(1) Page1

- it has 4 icons as such that

1a) itemIcon1.png is currently selected by default, it has dark color tone Icon to show it is the current selected icon.
1b) the other icons have NO darkcolor tone, this show they are not selected.

on Page1, when ItemIcon2.png is selected and clicked, it will navigate to Page2

(2) in Page2.

2a) itemIcon2.png will have a darkcolor tone to indicate it is currently selected icon.
2b) the other icons with No darktone color

**Problem:**

When navigated fom Page1 to Page2, How to reference the MenuItem2 and change the icon from LightTone Icon to DarkTone icon (say,itemIcon2Dark.png)

```
Page1 and Page2 will have the same number of icons

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="CheckList"
             x:Class="mmy.View.MainPage">    

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon1.png" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon2.png" Priority="1" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem3" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon3.png" Priority="2" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem4" Order="Primary"  Icon="itemIcon4.png" Priority="3" />

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="Page1"/>             
        </StackLayout>        

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Thanks

Comment: Toolbar is done on each page. Why you don't use different images? For example on Page 1 the image icon2 will be dark and on Page 2 icon2 will be icon2_light.

Comment: On Page1, the user can select any one of the remaining 3 icons. Say, icon2 is light tone in Page1, when user select it and it navigate to page2, this icon2 will have dark tone color icon to show it is selected one.

Comment: Again, what is the problem? Each page has it's own toolbar. You know in advance on which page what icons should be, don't you?